TypeScript assertion function that returns asserted value
I have the following assertions function:
export function assertNonNull<T>(
  value: T,
): asserts value is NonNullable<T> {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    throw new Error();
  }
}

This allows me to do (A):
const foo: string | null = getFoo();
assertNonNull(foo);
const bar: string = foo;

without the type system complaining that foo might be null.
But I also want to be able to do (B):
const foo: string | null = getFoo();
const bar: string = assertNonNull(foo);

I can change the above function to
export function assertNonNull<T>(
  value: T,
): NonNullable<T> {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return value as NonNullable<T>;
}

This allows me to do (B) but then I can no longer do (A).
How can I make a single function that lets me do both (A) and (B)?

• NonNullable<T> excludes undefined too but your code doesn't reflect that. Please [edit] to either check == null or to return T & ({} | undefined), so as not to be distracting from your question. • You can't. There's a feature request at ms/TS#40562. You'll need to have two functions to do the two things, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks @jcalz.
My actual code also has || value === undefined but I edited it down for conciseness. I thought it wouldn't make a difference because foo in my example is of type string | null, not string | null | undefined. But I've added it back to avoid confusion.
And yes, thanks for the (unfortunate) answer and the link to the corresponding feature request.

@DanielA.White
That question does appear to be the same question (or a more general case). But it did not show up in my Google searches or in the "Similar questions" that StackOverflow offered me. So perhaps it could be helpful to have the question worded in a different way so it's easier to find one of the two questions?
